# Поисковик на Delphi

Tags: поиск, delphi

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать поисковик на Delphi? У меня есть программа, которая находит нужное слово (слово вводится в Memo) в тексте, который загружен в RichEdit и выделяет его цветом.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender:TObject);  
const 
//Разделители слов. 
D= ['.', ',',':', ';', '!', '?', '-', ' ',#9,#10, #13];
//Величина приращения длины массива.  
Capacity=10;

var  S, sWord : String;  ArrW : array of String;  i, j, Pos1, Len, LenW :Integer;

begin 
//Формируем массив искомых слов. 
S := Memo1.Text; 
Len := Length(S); 
Pos1 := 0; 
j := 0;   
for i := 1 to Len do begin 
//Пропускаем разделители. 
if S[i] in D then Continue; 
//Отслеживаем начало слова. 
if (i = 1) or (S[i - 1] in D) then Pos1 := i; 
//Отслеживаем конец слова. 
if (i = Len) or (S[i + 1] in D) then begin  
//Длина слова. 
LenW := i - Pos1 + 1;
//Слово.
sWord := Copy(S, Pos1, LenW);
//Если требуется, увеличиваем длину массива.
if j = Length(ArrW) then SetLength(ArrW, j + Capacity);
//Добавляем слово в массив.
ArrW[j] := sWord;
//Индекс следующего элемента массива.
Inc(j);
end;   
end;   
//Изменяем длину массива, в соответствие с количеством добавленных   
//в него слов.   
if j < Length(ArrW) then SetLength(ArrW, j);
//Поиск и выделение заданных слов в тексте RichEdit.   
S := RichEdit1.Text;   
Len := Length(S);   
Pos1 := 0;   
for i := 1 to Len do begin
//Пропускаем разделители.
if S[i] in D then Continue;
//Отслеживаем начало слова.
if (i = 1) or (S[i - 1] in D) then Pos1 := i;
//Отслеживаем конец слова.
if (i = Len) or (S[i + 1] in D) then begin
//Длина слова.
LenW := i - Pos1 + 1;
//Слово.
sWord := Copy(S, Pos1, LenW);
//Проверяем - есть ли это слово в массиве.
for j := 0 to High(ArrW) do begin
if AnsiUpperCase(ArrW[j]) = AnsiUpperCase(sWord) then begin
//Если есть - выделяем его.
//(Pos1 - 1) - потому что символы в TRichEdit нумеруются от нуля.
RichEdit1.SelStart := Pos1 - 1;
RichEdit1.SelLength := LenW;
RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clRed;
Break;
end;
end;
end;   
end;
//Удаляем из памяти динамический массив.   
Finalize(ArrW); 
end;
```

Но проблема в том, что если нужное слово находится за пределами компонента (допустим, слово находится в 5-й строке RichEdit-а, а на форме в нем видно только 3 строки), то программа его выделяет, но там, внизу. То есть пользователь его не видит. Надо вручную опустить курсор, чтобы увидеть. А хотелось бы, чтобы слово само "поднималось" в видимое поле компонента. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
RichEdit1.SelStart:= 2000; //Позиция с начала документа
SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_SCROLLCARET, 0, 0);
```

ЗЫ Не проверял

Comment: Ок,спасибо! В принципе,выкрутилась иначе,через ListBox и Edit. Проще и вполне прилично вышло